# What would be a good strategy to fill up the buffer pool for a running mysql instance?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, database-administration

I'm doing some testing on MySQL, and a newbie to what I'm trying to do. I wanted to know of a good strategy to fill up the innodb buffer pool. I was thinking that doing too many inserts should do the task. Would be happy if someone can confirm it.

Thanks!

Comment: " . A table scan (such as performed for a mysqldump operation, or a SELECT statement with no WHEREclause) can bring a large amount of data into the buffer pool and evict an equivalent amount of older data, even if the new data is never used again. "  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really easy way would be to allocate a large enough buffer pool, create a simple table just consisting of one string, and use LOAD DATA INFILE with a file that consists of a lot of randomly generated strings. Doing so would fill the buffer pool up.

Answer (score 0):

what you are saying is right but after reading the strategy that is being used by the innodb to operate the buffer pool lies in the LRU algorithm.
to use the buffer pool more conveniently what you have to do is to warm up the data that is there in the buffer pool.
because the data that is being used frequently by the innodb engine from the buffer pool would be the data that will be young or you can say the data that would reside in the warm-up part of the buffer pool.

there are many scripts that are available on the Internet to warm up the buffer pool using the LRU algorithm.

when it comes to the allocation of the memory to the innodb_buffer_pool then you should set it to an optimal size that other processes running in the operating system will not become slow, In short there should be enough memory for the operating system's native processes.

if you will allocate the more memory to the buffer then there is a risk of page fault because of the low memory available for the OS's native processes.